# neo4j in Dockerfile - "service neo4j-service start" not detaching

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, docker, digital-ocean

I am installing neo4j as part of a bigger set up in a docker container (*not* a standalone neo4j image).
First I test it on windows in a docker-machine VM and it builds and runs like charm.
Then I take it to Digital Ocean and it builds too but when reaching `service neo4j-service start` in the Dockerfile, it shows

```
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [138]... waiting for server to be ready............................
```

and the dots keep adding - no failure, no detach. 
If I log into the container and just run `service neo4j-service start` this same thing happens. However in this case if I ^C the process and check status, neo4j is running and replying on 7474.

So this is really not about starting the service but about detaching

I tried (in a running container):

- updating java to oracle 8 (sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer)
- running neo4j directly (/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j start)

The result if always the same: the process would not detach, keeping the dots going, the service runs fine after breaking out of the process.

Some system info (from the container, built from the default ubuntu image):

```
root@04b1ec55572e:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Reelease:        14.04
Cdename:       trusty

root@04b1ec55572e:/# ulimit  -n
524288
```

Host system:

```
/# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

The only option I see now is running the command in background (`service neo4j-service start &`), sleep for 2-3 seconds and then check with `ps` if the service is running, but why would this terrible measure be needed in the first place.

Any help is appreciated.

Logs: https://gist.github.com/koacms-deployment/dc5afb2a8a371237cfd8

Dockerfile:

```
# Get neo4j
RUN wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key| apt-key add - # Import our signing key
RUN echo 'deb http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list # Create an Apt sources.list file
RUN apt-get update -y # Find out about the files in our repository
RUN apt-get install neo4j -y # Install Neo4j, community edition

# update neo4j listen ip to current ip
RUN sed "s/#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0/org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0/" -i /etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties

# ... a bit later ...

RUN service neo4j-service start
```

Comment: Which docker file did you use?

Comment: Use docker exec /bin/bash to go into the running image and check data/log/neo4j.log and data/graph.db/messages.log for errors and report them back.

Comment: thanks Michael for being so quick on those questions and sorry I couldn't find any help in your previous responses. I've updated the question with the log. 
I also managed to get all the "after 120 seconds" errors when doing other things like access rights wrong, but the way it is now there's nothing wrong with the logs. 
I'm using my own docker file, adding that as well to the question

Comment: moved the logs to a gist: https://gist.github.com/koacms-deployment/dc5afb2a8a371237cfd8

Comment: I finally  realized /bin/neo4j is just a shell script doing exactly that - sleeping and checking. so looking inside the script, apparently lsof is not returning what the script expects. This is true if I try running lsof manually too when the server is running (checked with wget http://localhost:7474). But netstat -a shows 7474 and 7473 are listened to. I keep looking but will appreciate ideas.

Answer (score 4):

So here's a summary of the investigation:

neo4j logs show nothing interesting, but looking into /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j (the neo4j executable starting the service) I realized that it uses lsof to check whether the process is ready listening on 7474 (or whatever port neo4j is configured to use).

lsof call in neo4j startup script was returning nothing even when I could confirm neo4j is already running both using netstat and direct request to neo4j REST endpoint.

Checking lsof revealed some "permission denied" messages related to neo4j.

Googling for something like "docker lsof permission denied" I found this little useful article: https://practiceml.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/permission-denied-for-lsof-in-docker/. The author had similar issues with  Linux Mint 17, but apparently it applies to Ubuntu as well.

The fix boils down to running this **on the host machine**:

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/docker
```

If you happen to not have aa-complain, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

Now while this does solve the issue, I will welcome comments regarding what security or other implications this might have.